# Mono for android : using Facebook binding

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to use the Facebook sdk api binding (https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook)

The bindings works only if I set the package name in the manifest to Com.Facebook.Android.

If I don't do this, I get an exception when I launch the login dialog (NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$drawable). The dialog tries to load a resource from the com.facebook.android package.

Is there a way to workaround this? My application cannot use Com.Facebook.Android as the package name, because it must be unique.

Comment: Finally, I modified the Facebook Sdk source to avoid the error and created my own binding.

Comment: Please could you explain exactly what you did? I encountered this problem and don't have an Eclipse environment set up in order to investigate Alfi's answer. Looking into Mono.Facebook's included "com.android.facebook.zip", it does have an R.class, it's just how to get my app to find it. Thanks.

Comment: My solution also needs an Eclipse environnement. I've just downloaded the Facebook SDK source code, remove any references to the R class and compiled into a jar.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, I resolved it a bit differently. After importing the project, go to Project Properties > Android > and Scroll Down to "Library" the package "com.facebook.android" should be listed there, select it and click on "Apply" and "OK". This will build the R.java for the facebook api, as the API generates a dialog the R.java is required.

If you dont see the package as said above, then the project was added as an External Jar. This will list it under "Referenced Libraries" in your Explorer.

Just import it as a project and follow as mentioned above.

Comment: Alfi: Are you doing this in Visual Studio? MonoDevelop?

Comment: I am doing this in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Alfi question was for Mono for Android (which I believe can't use eclipse, VS or Xamarin Studio).